# php variable $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is blank when using crontab

Tags: php

I have a small script which gets basic information like the server IP-, and the MAC-address of the server the script is running on, I am then posting the results to a mysql database, this works fine and the code is shown below. However when I use a cronjob to execute the script everything but the IP address is being stored, for some reason the `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is blank when being executed as a cronjob.

This script runs every min, and is run on multi Raspberry PI's so I can tell which is connected to share job requests.

```
$mac_address    = getMacLinux();
$server_ip      = $config['server_ip'];
$client_ip      = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$client_name    = $config['client_name'];


$ch = curl_init();
$url = "{$server_ip}/checkin0.php";
echo "url = {$url}"."<br>";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_ip={$client_ip}&client_name={$client_name}&client_mac={$mac_address}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // Execute

curl_close ($ch); // Close cURL handle

var_dump($output); // Show output
```

Comment: It's related to the fact that you are not executing this over HTTP but as a CLI script. Try something like `gethostname` or `exec`

Comment: thanks, a bit more searching using gethostname and cli got me the answer

Answer (score 0):

i found the following

```
function getServerAddress() {
    if(isset($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]))
    return $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];
    else {
    // Running CLI
    if(stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) {
        //  Rather hacky way to handle windows servers
        exec('ipconfig /all', $catch);
        foreach($catch as $line) {
        if(eregi('IP Address', $line)) {
            // Have seen exec return "multi-line" content, so another hack.
            if(count($lineCount = split(':', $line)) == 1) {
            list($t, $ip) = split(':', $line);
                $ip = trim($ip);
            } else {
                $parts = explode('IP Address', $line);
                $parts = explode('Subnet Mask', $parts[1]);
                $parts = explode(': ', $parts[0]);
                $ip = trim($parts[1]);
            }
            if(ip2long($ip > 0)) {
            echo 'IP is '.$ip."\n";
            return $ip;
            } else
            ; // TODO: Handle this failure condition.
        }
        }
    } else {
        $ifconfig = shell_exec('/sbin/ifconfig eth0');
        preg_match('/addr:([\d\.]+)/', $ifconfig, $match);
        return $match[1];
    }
```

Comment: I'm affraid, this solution useful if your network interface is single. If you have many interfaces you have to set IP-address in config

Comment: i just realised this when i noticed they are using shell_exec and parsing the  output. and depending where i connect my raspberry pis i use either the port or wifi dongle which will cause the issue you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are **created by the web server**

PS. Also you can use your script as CGI script (and $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDRESS'] will be correct). You may try fetch, wget, curl... and call script from crontab i.e. (server-IP is 192.168.0.1):

```
1 * * * * fetch http://192.168.0.1/my_script.php
```

Comment: my problem with that is i need to know the ip address of the raspberry pi first, what im doing instead is dropping the servers ip address in a config file, and then no matter how the raspberry connects it sends its ip to the server in an online list and then the server knows the ips to communicate with with out me having to do anything else.

Comment: You may obtain Raspberry IP-address from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in __checkin0.php__

Comment: that doesnt work when using crontab to execute the script, either.